# Refactor method by removing else condition

Tags: java

Given the below code is there a way to eliminate the `else` clause from the below method?
In my workplace `else` clause is considered evil because it somehow decreases the readability of the code.

```
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDateFromParam, String endDateFromParam, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
    boolean isDateRangeValid = true;
    final boolean requestContainsCustomDate = requestContainsCustomDate(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);

    if(requestContainsCustomDate || sessionContainsCustomDate(session)) {
        if(requestContainsCustomDate) {
            if(!isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam)) {
                isDateRangeValid = false;
                startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
                endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
            }
        } else {
            startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
            endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
        }
        setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
    }
    return isDateRangeValid;
}
```

Comment: While you have 3 answers, I would like to suggest that you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can get some points on this site. The title of the question should indicate what the code does rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: I get the feeling that your workplace is trying to fight *cyclomatic complexity* by banning else statements but not realizing that this leads to incredible increase in *cognitive complexity*. You could read into these and try to educate your coworkers. There are static code analysis tools that can be used for measuring these within the build process and you should use them instead of making blanket bans on normal programming structures. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_complexity

Comment: And in case some of your coworkers read this: banning else statements is *not normal*. If that came up in a job interview I would prefer to choose another place to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Else is evil"? That's a very peculiar point of view!

But if you really want to avoid it, you can look at early return, provided that isn't also regarded as evil - some people are very firm on the "single entry, single exit" principle.

Gilbert Le Blanc's code takes a similar approach to me, but in avoiding early return, he risks duplicated code execution, which may not be a problem here, but worries me a little.

The code below is not checked in any detail, but shows the idea, though it does duplicate code.

```
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDateFromParam, String endDateFromParam, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {

  if (requestContainsCustomDate(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam)) {
    boolean isDateRangeValid = isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);
    if (!isDateRangeValid) {
      startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
      endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
    }
    setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
    return isDateRangeValid;
  }

  if (sessionContainsCustomDate(session)) {
    startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
    endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
    setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I like the method in general. Its functionality seems more than a little messy, but without any background I'm not sure what can be done with it.

Comment: Agreed with your comment, the above is bad code because it uses output parameters; it is a chunk of code extracted from a method that is around 1000 lines long and I can't do much about it as it would require me to refactor the entire method.

Answer (score 2):

If I read correctly, the flow is:

```
if(A || B)
{
 if(A)
 {
   if(C)
   {
     ...
   }
 }
 else
 {
   ...
 }
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
if(A)
{
 b = true
 if(C)
 {
   ...
   b = false
 }
 ...
 return b;
}
if(B)
{
 ...
}
return true
```

So, in essence getting rid of the else can be done like this:

```
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDateFromParam, String endDateFromParam, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
    final boolean requestContainsCustomDate = requestContainsCustomDate(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);

    if(requestContainsCustomDate) {
        boolean isDateRangeValidResult = true;

        if(!isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam)) {
            isDateRangeValidResult = false;
            startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
            endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
        }

        setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);

        return isDateRangeValidResult;
    }

    if(sessionContainsCustomDate(session))
    {
        startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
        endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
        
        setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
    }

    return true;
}
```

If I didn't had to follow some company view about the readability of a statement, I would write instead:

```
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDateFromParam, String endDateFromParam, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
    boolean isDateRangeValidResult = true;
    final boolean requestContainsCustomDate = requestContainsCustomDate(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);

    if(requestContainsCustomDate) {
        if(!isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam)) {
            isDateRangeValidResult = false;
            startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
            endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
        }
        setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);    
    }
    else if(sessionContainsCustomDate(session))
    {
        startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
        endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
        setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);    
    }

    return isDateRangeValidResult;
}
```

Comment: Your second example calls setSessionAttributes under conditions where the original would not have done. This may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: You are right. I'm fixing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR, the code could be refactored as below. There are several things that can be improved, so please have a look at my comments at the bottom.

```java
    public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDate, String endDate, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
        final boolean isCustomDateIncludedInRequest = isCustomDateIncludedInRequest(startDate, endDate);

        boolean isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession = isCustomDateIncludedInRequest || isCustomDateIncludedInSession(session);
        if (!isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean isDateRangeValid = isDateRangeValid(startDate, endDate);
        boolean shouldDefaultDatesBeAddedToTheSession = !isCustomDateIncludedInRequest || !isDateRangeValid;
        if (shouldDefaultDatesBeAddedToTheSession) {
            startDate = getDefaultStartDate(session);
            endDate = getDefaultEndDate(session);
        }

        setSessionAttributes(startDate, endDate, session);
        return isCustomDateIncludedInRequest ? isDateRangeValid : true;
    }

    private String getDefaultEndDate(HttpSession session) {
        return session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
    }

    private String getDefaultStartDate(HttpSession session) {
        return session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
    }
```

**Step by step refactoring and the reasoning behind each change**

This is the original code:

```java
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDateFromParam, String endDateFromParam, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
    boolean isDateRangeValid = true;
    final boolean requestContainsCustomDate = requestContainsCustomDate(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);

    if(requestContainsCustomDate || sessionContainsCustomDate(session)) {
        if(requestContainsCustomDate) {
            if(!isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam)) {
                isDateRangeValid = false;
                startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
                endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
            }
        } else {
            startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
            endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
        }
        setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
    }
    return isDateRangeValid;
}
```

The code is indeed quite difficult to read, with code duplication and nested ifs. It is not about that single else that you are referring to, but there is a range of things that can be done to make the code cleaner and concise.

When the whole body of the function is executed when a condition is true, which seems to be the case here, you can return early. Please have a look at [Replacing Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html) refactoring technique for more information.

But before, let us first simplify the condition of the first if, using the [Extract Conditional](https://refactoring.guru/extract-variable) refactoring technique as below:

```java
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDateFromParam, String endDateFromParam, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
    boolean isDateRangeValid = true;
    final boolean requestContainsCustomDate = requestContainsCustomDate(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);

    boolean isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession = requestContainsCustomDate || sessionContainsCustomDate(session);
    if(isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession) {
        if(requestContainsCustomDate) {
            if(!isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam)) {
                isDateRangeValid = false;
                startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
                endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
            }
        } else {
            startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
            endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
        }
        setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
    }
    return isDateRangeValid;
}
```

Following that, we put the guard clause in place. We automatically remove one level of the `if`:

```java
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDateFromParam, String endDateFromParam, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
    boolean isDateRangeValid = true;
    final boolean requestContainsCustomDate = requestContainsCustomDate(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);

    boolean isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession = requestContainsCustomDate || sessionContainsCustomDate(session);
    if (!isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession) {
        return true;
    }
    if (requestContainsCustomDate) {
        if (!isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam)) {
            isDateRangeValid = false;
            startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
            endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
        }
    } else {
        startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
        endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
    }
    setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
    return isDateRangeValid;
}
```

I can then see that you have a boolean variable called `isDateRangeValid` which is set to true in the beginning of the method. Then, in the inner `if` you do the following:

```java
if (!isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam)) {
    isDateRangeValid = false;
    ///...
}
```

That can be replaced as below. I have also moved the `isDateRangeValid` closer to where it is used.

```java
boolean isDateRangeValid = true;
if (requestContainsCustomDate) {
    isDateRangeValid = isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);
    if (!isDateRangeValid) {
        startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
        endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
    }
} 
//...
```

If we replace the value of `isDateRangeValid` with the actual call, it becomes as below:

```java
//...
boolean isDateRangeValid = isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);
if (requestContainsCustomDate) {
    if (!isDateRangeValid) {
        startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
        endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
    }
} else {
    startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
    endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
}

setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
return requestContainsCustomDate ? isDateRangeValid : true; // The change has been reflected here as well.
```

Here, it is easier to see the code duplication! The following part is repeated twice!

```java
startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
```

Thus, we can remove the duplication (and the `else`) by *enhancing the conditional* as below:

```java
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDateFromParam, String endDateFromParam, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
    final boolean requestContainsCustomDate = requestContainsCustomDate(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);

    boolean isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession = requestContainsCustomDate || sessionContainsCustomDate(session);
    if (!isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession) {
        return true;
    }

    boolean isDateRangeValid = isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);
    if (!requestContainsCustomDate || (requestContainsCustomDate && !isDateRangeValid)) {
        startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
        endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
    }

    setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);
    return requestContainsCustomDate ? isDateRangeValid : true;
}
```

**Bonus section**:

Based on *[Propositional Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus)*, the expression in the `if` can be simplified even more.

This statement `(i)`:

`!requestContainsCustomDate || (requestContainsCustomDate && !isDateRangeValid)`    i.e. `!p || (p && !q)`

And this statement `(ii)`:

`!requestContainsCustomDate || !isDateRangeValid` i.e. `!p || !q`

**are exactly the same**!

You can verify this argument by testing the two expressions in the [Standford University truth table tool](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/).

**Cool bonus statement**: The results are exactly the same with this expression `(iii)` as well `!(requestContainsCustomDate && isDateRangeValid)` ([De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

I am going to use expression `(ii)`:

`!requestContainsCustomDate || !isDateRangeValid`

Which is extremely clear since it translates as below! **IF** the user did not request a custom date OR of the dates requested are not valid, use the default dates.

So, back to code. We make the replacement as below:

```java
//...

boolean isDateRangeValid = isDateRangeValid(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam);
if (!requestContainsCustomDate || !isDateRangeValid) {
    startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
    endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
}
//...
```

And we can make our intentions more clear by extracting the condition into a variable called `shouldDefaultDatesBeAddedToSession`:

```java
//...
boolean shouldDefaultDatesBeAddedToSession = !requestContainsCustomDate || !isDateRangeValid;
if (shouldDefaultDatesBeAddedToSession) {
    startDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
    endDateFromParam = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
}
//...
```

We are missing the surrounding methods (e.g. `setSessionAttributes` etc). I am sure that we could also make it even cleaner, since there are still code smells in the code.

**Further improvements / concerns**:

1. *Single Responsibility Principle*: This is my most important concern. This method does many things! A method should be responsible for one thing only ([Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)) and should do that very well. Please break it down to do less stuff! This brings us to the:
2. *[Command-Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)*. Strive to separate the methods that DO something and have side effects from the methods that RETURN something. Also, please have a look at the [Pure Functions](https://medium.com/better-programming/what-is-a-pure-function-3b4af9352f6f).
3. *Stick to naming conventions for better clarity*. Avoid naming your variables like `requestContainsCustomDate`. Please stick to the related Java naming conventions. An alternative naming could be `isCustomDatePresent`. Boolean methods should start with `is` or if it makes more sense with `has`, `can`, or `should`.
4. *OOP*! I see a lot of methods in the code, that take objects as parameters, to perform actions on those objects. For example, if possible, add the setSessionAttributes to the session object (or a wrapper/decorator of it), rather than passing the session in a method AND changing that session. A method from your method that does this is `setSessionAttributes(startDateFromParam, endDateFromParam, session);`
5. Avoid noise when naming stuff. For example, in the`startDateFromParam` and `endDateFromParam` function arguments, the `FromParam` is noise. You can change the variables to `startDate` and `endDate`.
6. Make your intentions clear / Name your intentions. One could argue otherwise, but you could extract strange or large statements to their own variables, so that you can make your intention clear. An example is the below:

`String defaultStartDate = session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();`

7. *BUG*? What is the intention of the return value? Do you want to return true if the dates requested have been successfully set? The function does not do that, so I have a suspicion that the return values could be wrong.

The method becomes:

````java
public boolean validateAndSetDateRelatedSessionAttributes(String startDate, String endDate, HttpSession session) throws ParseException {
    final boolean isCustomDateIncludedInRequest = isCustomDateIncludedInRequest(startDate, endDate);

    boolean isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession = isCustomDateIncludedInRequest || isCustomDateIncludedInSession(session);
    if (!isCustomDateIncludedInRequestOrSession) {
        return true;
    }

    boolean isDateRangeValid = isDateRangeValid(startDate, endDate);
    boolean shouldDefaultDatesBeAddedToTheSession = !isCustomDateIncludedInRequest || !isDateRangeValid;
    if (shouldDefaultDatesBeAddedToTheSession) {
        startDate = getDefaultStartDate(session);
        endDate = getDefaultEndDate(session);
    }

    setSessionAttributes(startDate, endDate, session);
    return isCustomDateIncludedInRequest ? isDateRangeValid : true;
}

private String getDefaultEndDate(HttpSession session) {
    return session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.END_DATE).toString();
}

private String getDefaultStartDate(HttpSession session) {
    return session.getAttribute(BACalendarConstant.START_DATE).toString();
}
```
````